# Convert mysql query to HQL

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

```
 select distinct gv.geoname,gv.GeoHierLevelCode,
 SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(gd.geohierpath,'/',4),'/',-1)
 from HavellsUserSalesForceMapping hs,geohiervalue gv,geohierpathdetails gd
 where hs.userCode = '00000001'
 and hs.cmpCode = gv.cmpCode
 and gv.geoCode IN (hs.geoCode)
 and gd.geohierpath LIKE CONCAT('%/',gv.geoCode,'/%') ;
```

SUBSTRING_INDEX is getting issue for me.Tell me the actual way to convert to hql

Answer (score 0):

Use [@Formula annotation](http://www.concretepage.com/hibernate/formula_hibernate_annotation) and define a dummy field for your expression. Then the field could be used in HQL query.